# Get the checked value of 2 sets of radiobuttons using jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Im having a weird issue here. Its probably just something stupid but I dont see it. I have two sets of radiobuttons, group1 and group2, and I want to get their values in a function.

I have 1 clickevent on all radiobuttons in that div and when I click them I want to display the check-values of both groups. But he only reads the value of the first group. and so it always displays 1-1 2-2 3-3 4-4 instead of possibly 1-2 3-1 etc....

There is a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UWcuh/) what am I missing??

Comment: i am used to xpath and have done the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `@` sign in your function:

```
function changeOutput() {
    gval1 = $("input:radio[name='group1']:checked").val();
    gval2 = $("input:radio[name='group2']:checked").val();
    $('#generator_output').text(gval1 + ' ' + gval2);
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UWcuh/1/)**

Comment: And voila, we have a winner!! Thanks man, been coding too long today I guess... Ill post this as the answer as soon as I can

Comment: No problem. It's Friday, I give you permission to leave work early.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdEx/

It looks like using the `@name` selector was messing things up.